# How to set timestamp manually on spring-ws security

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws, ws-security

Client and server do not have sync time so that the soap server's security return not authorized responses.
I will get the server's current time and I will use that time while sending the soap request(On security header, username token created vs).

How to set timestamp manually on spring-ws.

I am using spring ws.client.core, ws.soap.security.wss4j2 (Wss4jSecurityInterceptor and WebServiceTemplate).
WS-Usernametoken is sent for security(nonce, username, password, created (I guess that created is the problem. I should set that.)
The server is onvif device.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following( source here [here](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/doacbook/Doc.View.cls?KEY=GSOAPSEC_sectokens))

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
<property name="validationActions" value="Timestamp"/>
<property name="timestampStrict" value="true"/>
<property name="timeToLive" value="10"/>
```

In Short, you can do the following

1. Call the Create() class method of %SOAP.Security.Timestamp
   `set ts=##class(%SOAP.Security.Timestamp).Create()`
2. Call the AddSecurityElement() method of the SecurityOut property of your web client or web service
    `do client.SecurityOut.AddSecurityElement(ts)e`
3. Send the SOAP message

Comment: Did you give it a try or there is some other solution you were looking for ?